# Python Sina Weibo Webscraping Issue

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm attempting to webscrape weibo and I have an issue with the account login. My goal is to perform a search on s.weibo.com with a list of queries stored in a .txt file. Below is the Python script. Everytime I run the code, it opens Weibo, enters the query successfully, and shows relevant articles. Yet, after a few seconds, a window pops up and asks me to login (which I already did). Does anyone know how to go around this problem? Thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import urllib
import urllib.parse 
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime
import time as systime
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import FirefoxProfile
import unicodecsv as csv
base_url = 'http://s.weibo.com/weibo/'
file = open(r'C:\Users\some.name\query.txt', encoding="utf8")
file_index = 6
def scrape():
    global file_index
    with open(r'C:\Users\some.name\query.txt', encoding="utf8") as f:
        each_query = f.readlines()
    each_query = [x.strip() for x in each_query]
    # print urllib.quote(urllib.quote(each_query[0]))
    for each in each_query:
        query = each
        s = each.split(';')
        keyword = s[0]# urllib.quote(urllib.quote(s[0]))
        date = s[1]
        start = s[2]
        end = s[3]
        page = s[4]
        scrape_each_query(keyword, date, start, end, page, query)
        file_index = file_index + 1

def scrape_each_query(keyword, date, start, end, page, query):
    real_keyword = keyword
    keyword = urllib.parse.quote(urllib.parse.quote(keyword))
    # login_url = 'http://m.weibo.com/'
    # driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    # driver.get(login_url)
    # driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    # string = '登录'
    # driver.find_element_by_link_text ( string.decode('utf-8') ).click()
    # driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    # driver.find_element_by_link_text(string.decode('utf-8') ).click()
    # savedCookies = driver.get_cookies()
    # # login code
    # pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies() , open("chrome.pkl","wb"))
    # driver.close()
    all_content = []
    all_time = []
#   profile = FirefoxProfile(r"C:\Users\keith.yuen\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ciyiapug.default-release")
#   driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
#   co = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#   co.add_argument('user-data-dir=/Users/xuzhouyin/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\some.name\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
    url = base_url + keyword + "&typeall=1&suball=1&timescope=custom:" + start + ":" + end + "&page=" + "1"
    driver.get(url)
    systime.sleep(5)
    for i in range(int(page)):
        url = base_url + keyword + "&typeall=1&suball=1&timescope=custom:" + start + ":" + end + "&page=" + str(i + 1)
        # url = "http://s.weibo.com/weibo/%25E5%2585%2583%25E6%2597%25A6&typeall=1&suball=1&timescope=custom:2016-12-31:2016-12-31&Refer=g"
        # chrome_options = Options()
        # chrome_options.add_argument("~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default");
        # co = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        # co.add_argument('/Users/xuzhouyin/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default')
        
        # for cookie in pickle.load(open("chrome.pkl", "rb")):
        #   driver.add_cookie(cookie)
        driver.get(url)
        
        # driver.magage().add_cookie(savedCookies)
        page_source = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
        content = soup.findAll("p", { "class" : "comment_txt" })
        time = soup.findAll("a", { "class" : "W_textb" })
        
        for each in content:
            all_content.append(each.get_text().encode('utf-8'))
        for each in time:
            each = each.get_text()
            each = each.encode('utf-8')
            time = ""
            if "月" in each:
                time = str(datetime.datetime.now().year) + "-" + each[0:each.index("月")] + "-" + each[(each.index("月") + 3):each.index("日")]
            else:
                time = each[0:each.index(" ")]
            all_time.append(time)
    driver.close()
    save_to_csv(file + str(file_index), real_keyword, date, all_content, all_time, query)

def save_to_csv(filename, keyword, date, content, time, query):
    with open('./output/' + filename + '.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel', encoding='utf-16')
        spamwriter.writerow(["query", "Post ID", "keyword", "event Date", "Post Content", "Post Time"])
        for i in range(len(content)):
            spamwriter.writerow([query, i + 1, keyword, date, content[i], time[i]])

scrape()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the real problem you meet is **How to log in successfully** or **How to avoid login in the script**.

From your code, it's hard to tell if you logged in successfully or why the login failed.

So, here is another idea for you to solve the problem: `use browser with default user data/profile to avoid login`.
Note: The premise is that you've already logged in weibo manually, while using your browser daily.

For more information, [a demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63495962/setting-user-data-profile-in-selenium-is-not-working-selenium-python/63497249?noredirect=1#comment112284444_63497249)

Comment: if it is useful, please let me know by clicking the USEFUL button in  front of this answer.

Comment: Hello, Peter! Thank you for your reply. I use Google Chrome daily and am already logged in on Weibo. Every time I run the code, it opens Weibo (not logged in) on a Google Chrome browser. That is when it asks me to log in, which I already did in my other Google Chrome before.

Comment: @MatthiasGallagher So, have you solved the problem?