# Setting user data/profile in Selenium is not working. Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

For some reason when I try to set my user data/profile it doesn't work. The code runs fine but once the browser launches I'm not logged in to my profile. How would I go about fixing this?

```
chrome_options.add_argument(
    "user-data-dir=/Users/devinhadley/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1/")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
    "excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Check the user data by typing chrome://version/  check Profile Path: C:/Users/~/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default and remove the /Default. That should be in the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `Profile 1` from `user-data-dir=xxx`, then try again

---

More information:

1. Open `chrome://version` in the browser to see what profile Chrome is using. such as `C:\Users\quanql\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
2. remove the `Default` at the end and use it as value of `user-data-dir=`. such as `user-data-dir=C:/Users/quanql/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/`
3. run the test case, it should work

If you do not remove the `Default` in the 2nd step, then while you are running test case, open chrome://version in the browser which launched by chromedriver, you will see the profile Chrome that is using is `C:\Users\quanql\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Default`. This is the reason, you just met the same problem.

Comment: This works awesome thanks! Just one question lets say I want to open profile 2 within that directory. How would I do it?