# Selenium logging in another session will log out the others

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, parallel-processing, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium, Chrome driver, Python, to access a site that require login.

I need to open Chrome window on one python session, driver 1, log in, navigate to subpage A and perform task A.

I'll need to open another Chrome window, another driver 2, log in, navigate to subpage B and perform task B. There may be task C, D, etc. that I need to perform after logging in.

The issue is the sessions are not knowing each other (or share cookies). Logging into window 2 will log out of window 1 and vice versa. I can only have 1 logged-in session at a time.

Any way to open different logged-in sessions of the same website ?

Answer (score 1):

When you create some drivers, they have nothing to do with each other, they use their own `user-data-dir`, that's why the drivers do not share cookies.

You can let all the drivers use the same `user-data-dir`, like this:

```py
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/quanql/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1/")
```

See more, [How to set data/profile in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63495962/setting-user-data-profile-in-selenium-is-not-working-selenium-python/63497249#63497249)